# hot key for correcting a typo in TeXShop

Tags: texshop

As I type (in TeXShop), quite frequently I notice that my previous word is underlined red by the spellchecker. Sometimes the typo is evident, sometimes less so to me. Is there a way to set up a hot key in TeXShop so that with pressing it, TeXShop autocorrects the previous word to the first suggestion on the autocorrect list?

Even though this may be not the word intended 100% of time, over all such hot key would be a time saver for me, given how much time I spend typing in TeXShop and correcting my typos.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Check the `Edit->Check Spelling While Typing` menu item (I guess that's already checked). Then also check the `Edit->Correct Spelling Automatically` menu item. I can't guarantee that corrects with the first item on the spelling list but, maybe, it does what you wish. On the other hand I find all of that stuff horrible and have both turned off. I check the spelling when I'm done writing the document or at some convenient time.

Comment: "Correct Spelling Automatically" would be too much for me, as I know that some words I need are not in the spellcheck dictionary and also I dont want a stealth autocorrection.